# Print Headers value of Postman

Tags: codeigniter, api, postman

I am trying to use rest api basic authentication and testing it through postman. On the authorization field, I used Type as Basic Auth and used the username and password in the field as in image below:
[image]

Then it automatically generates the following on Header :
[image]

So what I basically want is to print the value of Authorization i.e `Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=` on my controller. Printing the username and password works fine with `print_r($this->input->server('PHP_AUTH_USER'))` and `print_r($this->input->server('PHP_AUTH_PW'))`. However I didn't find a way to print the value from header field. Is there any best practice to achieve this. Any help appreciated. Thank You !

Comment: You can check this link hope it helps in getting you a correct overview of what you are trying to do http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/02/20/using-variables-inside-postman-and-collection-runner/

Comment: Thanks @Abizz that's a useful blog however I don't find any solution to my problem there. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

just copy paste this code and you get your output in this format ==>

> Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=

```
$token = $this->input->get_request_header('Authorization');
print_r($token);
die;
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is you want to print the value from the header.
There is a way to print it to the console or to the Test tab.

```
var (name) = postman.getResponseHeader("value-you-want-to-print");

// to console 
console.log((name));

// to Test
tests[(name)] = (name);
```

Comment: How to do this for request header?

Comment: console.log(request.headers['from']) this one worked. 

But only issue. small case only works even if header name was 'From'